# hide specific point in a HighCharts scatterplot

Tags: highcharts, hide, scatter

I need to hide a specific point in a HighCharts scatterplot. I've tried to setting series.point.visible that it's not the right way... See http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/28/. 
Which is the right code to insert for #button click function?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    symbol:'circle',
                    fillColor: '#800000'
                },
            }
        },
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        color: "#b0b0b0",
        data: [[38,42],[39,39],[35,45],[35,54],{x:36,y:35}]
        }]
});
var chart=$('#container').highcharts();
});
$('#button').click(function () {
    chart.series[0].data[3].visible=(!chart.series[0].data[3].visible);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/55tkvfbn/ is this acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of options

Hide the marker:

```
  $('#button').click(function() {
    // This is an option, but you'd also need to hide the label and tooltip for it to be usable 
    // the data is still in the series
    var data = chart.series[0].data;
    var point = data[3];
    if (point.marker && point.marker.enabled == false) {
      data[3].marker = {
        enabled: true,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      };
    } else {
      data[3].marker = {
        enabled: false,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      };
    }
    chart.series[0].setData(data);
  });
```

Remove the point from the series

```
  $('#button2').click(function() {
    // This requires that you keep your original data somewhere, so you can add it back in.  
    // I'm also using a flag to track if the data is hidden or not.  
    // You could check that the series matches the saved data if you'd rather or 
    // keep track of a point and add and remove that.
    var series = chart.series[0];
    if (hidden) {
      myData = origData.slice();
      series.setData(myData);
      hidden = false;
    } else {
      series.removePoint(3);
      hidden = true;
    }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/31/

Though I like Deep 3015's suggestion from the comments also